Monster fish B-movie in which monster comes out of human's body during intercourse
This is probably a long shot. I watched about 20 minutes of this monster fish movie when I was teenager and I remember only one scene vividly. The movie has a bunch of vacationers(2 couples if I remember correctly) near a sea/ocean. The scene I remember is that of a couple having sex and during the sex, the monster comes out of the male's throat destroying his body and dripping blood into the girl's lips and the monster continues to have sex with the girl impregnating her. Later the girl gives birth to monster's offspring (or is killed/ kills the offspring - I don't remember.)  

Genre : Horror
Year  : 1992-2002
Language : English (I think)
Cast : Predominantly white 

Apologies for being so vague but that is all I remember. I've searched a lot for this movie but had no luck. I'm beginning to question if if it's all in my head now.

Marked as a duplicate since it sounds like Plankton (see link above). If this isn't the film you're looking for, please let me know.
